# Converting images into video throwing Out of memory error, even though used is around 8GB but I have 64GB

Tags: python, opencv, out-of-memory

Trying to convert images into video but getting this error,

> File "C:/test.py", line 35, in 
>       convert_frames_to_video(pathIn, pathOut, fps)   File "C:/test.py", line 17, in convert_frames_to_video
>       img = cv2.imread(filename) 
>   cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-
>   python\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:55: 
>   error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 72000000 bytes in
>   function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'

Used memory in task manager is 8GB total memory is 64GB... I am running this code using PyCharm IDE,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

from os.path import isfile, join

def convert_frames_to_video(pathIn, pathOut, fps):
    frame_array = []
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn, f))]

    for i in range(len(files)):
        filename = pathIn + "\\" + files[i]
        # reading each files
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        print(filename)
        height, width, layers = img.shape
        size = (width, height)
        print(filename)
        # inserting the frames into an image array
        frame_array.append(img)

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), fps, size)

    for i in range(len(frame_array)):
        # writing to a image array
        out.write(frame_array[i])
    out.release()

pathIn = 'C:\\Images'
pathOut = 'video.avi'
fps = 25.0
convert_frames_to_video(pathIn, pathOut, fps)
```

Comment: Is this Python 32-bit or 64-bit? Anyway, just move the out.write inside the loop: read image, write frame.

Comment: good shout, 32 bit...

Comment: I've been bitten by that before!

Comment: thanks mate, I installed the 64 bit exe, but pycharm still doesn't likes it, I will try your 2nd suggestion, guess I don't need to change anything and pycharm would use 64bit version itself, also pycharm seems to be 64 bit too

Comment: Why not just write the frames directly to the video as you read them? Right now, the only thing that `frame_array` really does is waste a lot of memory...